# I would like to hyperlink several headings with different styles to the TOC without the style changing?

Tags: microsoft-word, hyperlink

I want to link the chapter headings, sub headings, etc, to the TOC in my Word doc but the hyperlink turns the headings underlined blue.

Modifying the hyperlink style makes all of my heading styles the same.

Also, I would prefer the hyperlinks were hidden or not obvious.

Grateful for any help.  Thanks!

Comment: https://www.lifewire.com/add-and-edit-links-word-documents-3539976  ?

Comment: I don't see anything in that document about changing link styles.

Answer (score 0):

After all the links are inserted, on the **Home** tab, in the **Styles** gallery (or in the separate **Styles** pane if it's open), right-click one of the heading styles, and click **Select All**. Then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Spacebar</kbd> to clear the blue font color and underlining. Repeat for every other heading style that's used. The appearance of the hyperlinked headings will match what's configured in the style definition for those headings.

Comment: I tried it with just one of the heading styles since I'm out of time.  You may be an absolute Genius!!  Will know for sure tomorrow.  Thanks so much!